2011 Buick lacrosse 3.6l overheating after replacing a lot of parts
Car is still over heating, say “ac off due to high engine temp”
I replaced the coolant hose connector, water pump, coolant temperature sensor, and thermostat.
The temperature gauge is not working after getting new coolant temperature sensor. Ac is still not working.
Hot air does blow out. Fan does turn on. Has new coolant.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you describe a little better when it is overheating? Is it all the time, when driving down the highway, or when sitting still in traffic? You stated the temp gauge is not working after new coolant temperature sensor. Did it work before you changed out the sensor? Have you plugged into your computer to get live data to see what the ECU thinks the coolant temp is? If so, is it correct there, or does it read high or low?

Ac not working may be a secondary problem, separate from engine overheating. Under most circumstances, replacing water pump, thermostat and coolant sensor should have new coolant with engine self purging air in the system. Does your vehicle have the pressure cap on the surge tank or on the radiator? Is the drive belt loose, possibly from a worn belt tensioner? The coolant temperature sensor may have a connector or wire damage, preventing the signal from being sent to the ecm and display. As mentioned, a good reader will show coolant temps unless connector/wiring damage occurred.
